# Split Swift Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array with some numbers downloaded from the web. It's an array that should be all the numbers downloaded from the web, but right now array[0] is just all the numbers, and array[1] is something that doesn't matter.

["\"100001986741004-2\",\"100003866283798-2\",\"100003455181526-2\",\"100002261472542-2\",\"100001986741004-3\",\"100001986741004-0\",\"100003866283798-3\",\"100003866283798-0\",\"100003455181526-3\",\"100003455181526-0\",\"100002261472542-3\",\"100002261472542-0\"", "\"groups\""]

I want each number serparated without the quotes and slashes etc, so I can display it into a tableviewcontroller, any idea how I could do this? Sometimes there could be 5 numbers, but it could also be 500..

any help is appreciated!

Comment: How did you download the data? It looks like you have a single string right now. Is it supposed to be JSON/

Comment: You think it would be better to store the numbers with JSON instead of just an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the commas are the actual delimiters, and then you've got quotes. I'm not sure if the

> \"

Strings are quotes that are backslash escaped for display, or if the string actually contains backslash quote.

I'd use the NSString method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to get rid of the quotes or backslash-quotes, and then use `componentsSeparatedByString:` with a comma delimiter to break the string into an array of number strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to emit one or some special characters from beginning and ending of String. So you are trimming it.

Use this code to trim quotation mark for an element:

```
array[0].stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\""))
```

if you want map entire array to this new format use this code:

```
let mappedArray = array.map {
    $0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\"")) 
}
```